# How to extract text by using imacros?

Tags: html, csv, extract, imacros

This is code:

```
<div style="" class="film">
    <div class="film_poster">
        <!--<div class="like_save">-->
        <div onclick="return login_please()" mov_id="12334" class="like_film_pub ">
            <span class="icon_like_film_pub"></span>
            <p><span>Like</span>
            </p>
        </div>

        <a class="tooltip1" href="link" style="outline: 1px solid blue;">
            <img width="134" height="193" alt="The Raid 2: Berandal" src="link">
        </a>
    </div>
    <a title="The Raid 2: Berandal (2014) " href="link">
        <figcaption>The Raid 2: Berandal (2014)</figcaption>
    </a>

</div>
```

Can you show me how to get text from above code by using imacros. With above example, it will extract **"The Raid 2: Berandal"**. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:link EXTRACT=TXT
```

This should work.